# Automatic data storage and analysis

Tags: database, excel, mean

My tast is to program something for a testing environment. The tester should enter a value and the program should be able to calculate the mean of the new value plus the old ones. The typed value should then be saved among the old values. The calculation should be carried out once again when new values are entered.
Any suggestions how I should go about the problem? I wish to execute this with Excel VBA, with one cell for data input and one cell for mean value. The old values should be saved on an extra sheet.

Any tips will be welcome here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `AVERAGE()`.

Here I used average on a range of 20 cells and it calculates the average of the filled cells.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the fast reply Andreas. I dont think this is what i am looking for as it only allows the tester to enter 20 values. Otherweise it needs a lot of cell space. I was looking for a solution with one cell for Input, one cell for Output, and a data bank for data storage on an extra sheet.

Comment: In that case you need VBA, something you did not mention. Update your question with a CLEAR question and what you are looking for in result